# Dependency Injection with priority / fallback and generics in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Let's say I have a generic interface and a generic class that implements it.

```
interface IRepository<TModel> { }

[RegisterGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>))]
class GenericRepository<TModel> : IRepository<TModel> { }
```

And two models `User` and `Order`. `User` has nothing special so it uses the generic repository implementation. `Order` is different, so I have a specific repository.

```
[Register(typeof(IRepository<Order>))]
class OrderRepository : GenericRepository<Order> { }
```

Meanwhile you can see I use two attributes so that I can scan the attributes and automatically register them to Unity when the application starts. What I want is:

1. `IRepository<User>` is mapped to `GenericRepository<User>`
2. `IRepository<Order>` is mapped to `OrderRepository`

for those new models in the feature, if a specific repository is added(like Order), the interface should be mapped to the specific implementation. Otherwise it's mapped to the generic one. How can I implement the priority function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity, when you make multiple registrations, Unity will build up a collection of registrations for you where the last registration becomes the 'default' registration. So in that respect, you should be able to do the following:

```cs
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));

// Override multiple specific implementations (I image batch registration here)
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Order>), typeof(OrderRepository));
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Customer>), typeof(CustomerRepository));
```

Comment: You are correct. I made another silly mistake, which causes everything work incorrectly.

Comment: By the way, even you register `IRepositry<Order>` before `IRepository<>`, the `IRepository<Order>` still has a higher priority, unity has already handled their priority, not only by registration order.

Comment: @DannyChen: Hmm, interesting, so this behavior is identical to how Simple Injector handles this. Open generic registrations are handled through unregistered type resolution, which means they are always used as fallback when a concrete registration is missing.